# Calculating layout using pure JS

Tags: javascript, css, algorithm, layout

May I have an object represents page elements with styles:

```
[{
   id: "widget-1",
   display: "block",
   float: "left",
   width: 100
}, {
   id: "widget-2",
   display: "block",
   float: "right",
   width: 200
}]
```

How to calculate coordinates and sizes of these elements positions without using browser's DOM by these algorithms http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#layout ? So that I see the result similar to:

```
[{
   "id": "widget-1",
   "width": 200,
   "height": 20,
   "top": 0,
   "left": 0,
   "right": 200,
   "bottom": 0,
}, {
   "id": "widget-2",
   "width": 200,
   "height": 20,
   "top": 0,
   "left": 200,
   "right": 0,
   "bottom": 0,
}]
```

Is there a library for this? I need fast calculation of this in browser, so javascript implementation would be useful.

I see that we have https://github.com/facebook/css-layout  , but supporting only "flex-box" layout.

Answer (score 0):

It's  "`quiet simple`", though you want to build from scratch the [CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model). Even [this entry point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Layout) in the serie might be helpful